# How do you verify that 2 copies of a VB 6 executable came from the same code base?

Tags: vb6, md5, hash, md5sum, binary-reproducibility

I have a program under version control that has gone through multiple releases.  A situation came up today where someone had somehow managed to point to an old copy of the program and thus was encountering bugs that have since been fixed.  I'd like to go back and just delete all the old copies of the program (keeping them around is a company policy that dates from before version control was common and should no longer be necessary) but I need a way of verifying that I can generate the exact same executable that is better than saying "The old one came out of this commit so this one should be the same."

My initial thought was to simply MD5 hash the executable, store the hash file in source control, and be done with it but I've come up against a problem which I can't even parse.

It seems that every time the executable is generated (method: Open Project. File > Make X.exe) it hashes differently.  I've noticed that Visual Basic messes with files every time the project is opened in seemingly random ways but I didn't think that would make it into the executable, nor do I have any evidence that that is indeed what's happening.  To try to guard against that I tried generating the executable multiple times within the same IDE session and checking the hashes but they continued to be different every time.

So that's:

1. Generate Executable
2. Generate MD5 Checksum: `md5sum X.exe > X.md5`
3. Verify MD5 for current executable: `md5sum -c X.md5`
4. Generate New Executable
5. Verify MD5 for new executable: `md5sum -c X.md5`
6. Fail verification because computed checksum doesn't match.

I'm not understanding something about either MD5 or the way VB 6 is generating the executable but I'm also not married to the idea of using MD5.  If there is a better way to verify that two executables are indeed the same then I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: And why not just assign a version number? then you immediatley know if it's older or the latest version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's going to be nearly impossible. Read on for why.

**The compiler will win this game, every time...**

Compiling the same project twice in a row, even without making any changes to the source code or project settings, will always produce different executable files.

One of the reasons for this is that the PE (Portable Executable) format that Windows uses for EXE files includes a timestamp indicating the date and time the EXE was built, which is updated by the VB6 compiler whenever you build the project. Besides the "main" timestamp for the EXE as a whole, each resource directory in the EXE (where icons, bitmaps, strings, etc. are stored in the EXE) also has a timestamp, which the compiler also updates when it builds a new EXE. In addition to this, EXE files also have a checksum field that the compiler recalculates based on the EXE's raw binary content. Since the timestamps are updated to the current date/time, the checksum for the EXE will also change each time a project is recompiled.

**But, but...I found this really cool EXE editing tool that can undo this compiler trickery!**

There are EXE editing tools, such as [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm), that claim to be able to adjust all the timestamps in an EXE file to a fixed time. At first glance you might think you could just set the timestamps in two copies of the EXE to the same date, and end up with equivalent files (assuming they were built from the same source code), but things are more complicated than that: the compiler is free to write out the resources (strings, icons, file version information, etc.) in a different order each time you compile the code, and you can't really prevent this from happening. Resources are stored as independent "chunks" of data that can be rearranged in the resulting EXE without affecting the run-time behavior of the program.

If that wasn't enough, the compiler might be building up the EXE file in an area of uninitialized memory, so certain parts of the EXE might contain bits and pieces of whatever was in memory at the time the compiler was running, creating even more differences.

**As for MD5...**

You are not misunderstanding MD5 hashing: MD5 will *always* produce the same hash given the same input. The problem here is that the input in this case (the EXE files) keep changing.

**Conclusion: Source control is your friend**

As for solving your current dilemma, I'll leave you with this: associating a particular EXE with a specific version of the source code is a more a matter of policy, which has to be enforced somehow, than anything else. Trying to figure out what EXE came from what version without any context is just not going to be reliable. You need to track this with the help of other tools. For example, ensuring that each build produces a different version number for your EXE's, and that that version can be easily paired with a specific revision/branch/tag/whatever in your version control system. To that end, a "free-for-all" situation where some developers use source control and others use "that copy of the source code from 1997 that I'm keeping in my network folder because it's *my code* and source control is for sissies anyway" won't help make this any easier. I would get everyone drinking the source control Kool-Aid and adhering to a standard policy for creating builds right away.

Whenever we build projects, our build server (we use [Hudson](http://www.hudson-ci.org/)) ensures that the compiled EXE version is updated to include the current build number (we use the [Version Number Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Version+Number+Plugin) and a custom build script to do this), and when we release a build, we create a tag in Subversion using the version number as the tag name. The build server archives release builds, so we can always get the specific EXE (and setup program) that was given to a customer. For internal testing, we can choose to pull an archived EXE from the build server, or just tell the build server to rebuild the EXE from the tag we created in Subversion.

We also never, ever, ever release any binaries to QA or to customers from any machine other than the build server. This prevents "works on my machine" bugs, and ensures that we are always compiling from a "known" copy of the source code (it only pulls and builds code that is in our Subversion repository), and that we can always associate a given binary with the exact version of the code that it was created from.

Comment: Wonderful answer, MikeyBoy. Your VB6 mastery truly knows no bounds. ;)

Comment: @MikeSpross Thanks for the informative response! Do you have any additional details on your paragraph, "If that wasn't enough..."? It sounds like this approach presents security issues, where possibly sensitive data that was in memory can get compiled into an EXE if that data was not securely cleared. Is there some restriction on what you're referring to as "memory at the time the compiler was running"? Thanks.

Comment: Example: We add the changeset ID from source control to the EXE and DLL metadata in every build

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while, but since there is VB De-compiler app, you may consider bulk-decompiling vb6 apps, and then feeding decompilation results to an AI/statistical anomaly detection on the various code bases. Given the problem you face doesn't have an exact solution, it is unlikely the results will be 100% accurate, but as you feed more data, the detection should become more and more accurate